# Rails on windows without kgio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

How can I install rails on Windows without kgio?

When I run 'rails server' it tries to install what I'm assuming is dependencies that it needs.  It fails once it tries to install kgio.  I've done a fair bit of searching and found that kgio doesn't work on Windows - is there a workaround for this?

i.e. 
Do I even need it?
If not... how do I remove it from the dependency list?
If I do need it, then what are my options?  Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you trying to run Unicorn? If that's the case you'll just have to replace your web server. Maybe [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)? If you decide to use Thin you'll need this in your Gemfile:

```
gem "eventmachine", ">= 1.0.0.beta"
gem 'thin'
```

Thin needs eventmachine but not all versions will do, you'll need the beta (pre-release) one.

Comment: It was a an application I inherited, and being a Rails noob I didn't have the first clue what was causing it not to run.  I did eventually figure out that it was Unicorn stopping it, so after commenting that out I just defaulted back to WEBrick and now it runs fine on Windows.